# ADF convertNumber throwing empty string?

Tags: string, converters, oracle-adf

So I've this code in my jspx page (valorTicket is a Double)

```
>                               <af:inputText value="#{bindings.valorTicket.inputValue}"
                                        label="Valor TAG" id="itValorTicket"
                                        required="false"  >

                            <af:convertNumber id="cnTicket" type="currency"  
                                              minFractionDigits="2" 
                                              maxFractionDigits="2"/>
                            <af:validateDoubleRange id="vdrTicket"
                                                    minimum="0.01"
                                                    maximum="10000000000000"
                                                    messageDetailNotInRange="O valor deve ser de R$ 0,01 até R$ 10.000.000.000.000,00"/>
                          </af:inputText>
```

When I just submit the input without changing it's initial value (empty) everything runs as it should, but when I set a number and submit then delete everything and submit a "Double.valueOf()" throws a numberFormatException: empty string, I've tried setting the following parameter in the web.xml

> javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL

But I still get the same error, even though the value submitted now is null.

Any thoughts in this?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing the JDeveloper release you work with. Can you provide the release so it can be reproduced ? Note that javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL is not available for all JDeveloper 11g releases

Comment: How can the JDeveloper version cause this problem? Could you elaborate more? The program is already being tested on a WebLogic server, and not in the integrated server that comes with JDeveloper, if that's what you meant. I'm using the 11g release 1(11.1.1.6.0).

Comment: Just to give some more informations we're using the JSF 1.2, so that's why even with javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL the converter was still getting an empty string. As I understand after doing some research the JSF 1.2 does not validate empty fields, if that's true why after I set a value, then delete it it's being validated?

Comment: Well, this is what you want to find out by posting to this forum. You said you use JDeveloper 11.1.1.6 so this allows me to run a test by myself as this was the missing information. The javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL is a JSF 2.0 feature and not available in JSF 1.2. So this is where the JDeveloper version matters